# Python ImportError: No module named wmi

Tags: python, import, wmi

I followed directions to download WMI for Python here

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html

When I attempt to run the code

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI ()
for s in c.Win32_Service (StartMode="Auto", State="Stopped"):
  if raw_input ("Restart %s? " % s.Caption).upper () == "Y":
    s.StartService ()
```

I receive the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\see_wmi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wmi
ImportError: No module named wmi
```

EDIT:

I am using Python 2.7.6

EDIT2:

I am running 64-bit Windows 2008 R2, and I downloaded WMI-1.4.9.zip (md5) from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/. I extracted the contents and saved it in D:\Python\Tools\Scripts. I executed

```
python setup.py.install
```

I added D:\Python\Tools\Scripts to %PATH%, and when I execute the code

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI ()
for s in c.Win32_Service (StartMode="Auto", State="Stopped"):
  if raw_input ("Restart %s? " % s.Caption).upper () == "Y":
    s.StartService ()
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\see_wmi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wmi
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 88, in <module>
    from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

EDIT3:

I now have Python 2.7.6 and the installation is D:\Python27

I extracted WMI-1.4.9.zip in D drive and executed the following

```
PS D:\WMI-1.4.9> python .\setup.py install
```

And the output is

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
copying wmi.py -> build\lib
running build_scripts
creating build\scripts-2.7
copying wmitest.py -> build\scripts-2.7
copying wmiweb.py -> build\scripts-2.7
copying wmitest.cmd -> build\scripts-2.7
copying wmitest.master.ini -> build\scripts-2.7
running install_lib
copying build\lib\wmi.py -> D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
byte-compiling D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wmi.py to wmi.pyc
running install_scripts
creating D:\Python27\Scripts
copying build\scripts-2.7\wmitest.cmd -> D:\Python27\Scripts
copying build\scripts-2.7\wmitest.master.ini -> D:\Python27\Scripts
copying build\scripts-2.7\wmitest.py -> D:\Python27\Scripts
copying build\scripts-2.7\wmiweb.py -> D:\Python27\Scripts
running install_data
warning: install_data: setup script did not provide a directory for 'readme.txt' -- installing right in 'D:\Python27'

running install_egg_info
Writing D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\WMI-1.4.9-py2.7.egg-info
```

But when I execute my original code, I get the same error

```
PS D:\SymantecDLP\Protect> python .\see_wmi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\see_wmi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wmi
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 88, in <module>
    from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

EDIT4:

And I included the following in %PATH%

```
D:\Python27;D:\Python27\Lib\;D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/ Did you download wmi from here?

Comment: @BenjiSparks - yes I downloaded from there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

I needed to install Python for Windows extensions located at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/

Since I am using Python 2.7.6 on 64-bit server I installed pywin32-218.**win-amd64-py2.7.exe**

Comment: I am using 64 bit windows 7, but 32 bit python 2.7 so I used pywin32-220.win32-py2.7.exe

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I have found is this:

If you are using python 2, you need to use

```
python setup.py install
```

Which will work for python 2, but not 3. In that case, you need to use

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.5

Comment: @Glowie The only thing I could suggest would be to try to reinstall it.

Comment: I reinstalled it and still it doesn't work. I included the details in my original question